# Validate Facebook DateTime String

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, facebook-graph-api, iso8601

I'm having some trouble in C# validating datetime strings for Graph.  The facebook API documentation shows:

```
2014-11-01T12:00-0300
```

as a date time format.  No matter what I try (even thinking they may have left out a ":" on the offset) it doesn't pass.  My code below:

```
public bool validateDateTimeISO8601(string s)
        {
            // you may want to add a few more formats here
            var formats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm-hh",
                      "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm-hh:mm",
                      "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm+hh",
                      "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm+hh:mm",
                      "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mmZ",
                      "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ" };

            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats,
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, // ISO is invariant
                                       DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, // this is important
                                       out dt))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
```

There are 6 formats in my formats array.  The last 2 pass, but the first 4 fail no matter what I throw at them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use http://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset part in that time `-0300` would be parsed by `zzz`, not `Z`. Check the 
[.Net Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for available format specifiers.

`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mmzzz` will parse the date `2014-11-01T12:00-0300` which you have shown.

The first 4 formats in your array would only parse dates when the offset matches the time. Eg. `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm-hh:mm` would give true for `2014-11-01T12:00-12:00` but false for `2014-11-01T12:00-03:00`. In those, I think you are expecting to use `hh` and `mm` for the offset, but these would be interpreted as the hour and minute of the time, not the offset. These aren't helpful for what you're trying to achieve, so remove them.

Comment: apparently I am the only one stupid enough not to catch the .Net Z z difference.  Worked perfectly.